# Vectorized Code on GPU

Tags: opencl

I am using OpenCL to execute a procedure on different GPUs and CPUs simultaneously to get a high performance results. The Intel OpenCL is always showing a message that the Kernel is not vectorized, so it will only run on different cores but will not run using SIMD instructions. My question is, if I rewrite the code so that the SIMD instruction can be exploit with the OpenCL code, will it increase the GPU Performance also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - but beware that this is not necessary on AMD GCN based APU/GPU or Nvidia Fermi or higher GPU hardware for good performance -they do scalar operations with great utilization.  CPUs and Intels GPU however can greatly benefit via SIMD instructions which is what the vector operations boil down to.

Comment: So, What I understood from your answer is that I should do that and then profile and see which one is better. Is that true?
or for sure, the vectorized code will work faster on GPU anyway?

Comment: well profiling is _never_ a bad idea but if you look into the hardware architecture you are programming for, you will easily have your answer at whether it is a good idea or a waste of time.  Just with this quick check you probably don't need to program anything up to know which to do.